# Joseph's Garment- Made or hand me down?

Tags: clothing, midrash, yosef, parashat-vayeishev, vayechi

Source 1: Targum Yerushalmi Bereishit 48:22 which says that Yosef coat was originally Adam's.
Source 2: Bereishit 37:3 Says Yaakov made Joseph's coat

How can this be resolved?

Source 1:
כב וַאֲנָא הָא יְהָבִית לָךְ חוּלַק חַד יַתִּיר עַל אֲחָךְ לְבוּשֵׁיהּ דְאָדָם קַדְמָאָה נְסִיב יָתֵיהּ אַבְרָהָם אָבוּי דְאַבָּא מִן יְדוֹי דְנִמְרוֹד רַשִׁיעָא וִיהַב יָתֵיהּ לְיִצְחָק אַבָּא וְיִצְחָק אַבָּא יְהַב יָתֵיהּ לְעֵשָו וַאֲנָא נְסָבִית יָתֵיהּ מִן יְדוֹי דְעֵשָו אָחִי לָא בְּחַרְבִּי וְלָא בְּקַשְׁתִּי אֱלָהֵין בִּזְכוּתִי וּבְעוֹבָדֵי טַבְיָא׃

Source 2:
וְיִשְׂרָאֵל אָהַב אֶת יוֹסֵף מִכָּל בָּנָיו כִּי בֶן זְקֻנִים הוּא לוֹ וְעָשָׂה לוֹ כְּתֹנֶת פַּסִּים׃

Comment: Maybe he tailored it to fit Joseph.

Answer (score 4):

The מעם לעז says Yaakov avinu added the sleeves, which is why it says ועשה. Yaakov made the sleeves for the cloak which originally belonged to Adam HaRishon.

Comment: welcome aboard and thanks for the excellent answer. It would be nice if you could give the exact page citation from Me'Am Lo'ez.

Answer (score 2):

עשה ("made") can also mean acquired, as in קנין. Among other places this is [stated](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36864&st=&pgnum=430&hilite=) in [ספר השרשים](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%92%27%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%97).

Interestingly the same Targum doesn't translate it that way on Bereishit 37:3. I guess he doesn't only choose one opinion for all verses, or perhaps as @Baby Seal [suggested](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34911/josephs-garment-made-or-hand-me-down#comment90478_34911), he further tailored it in some way.